# Selecting column alias filled with NULLs with Zend_Db

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Is there any way you can select NULL as a column with Zend_db.
To make it clear, you could write a query:

```
SELECT id, name, age, NULL as ssn from dummy_table;
```

The result would have 4 columns id, name, age and ssn(filled with null). Is there any way to do this in Zend_Db. My guess was:

```
$columns = [
    'id' => 'id',
    'name' => 'name',
    'age' => 'age',
    NULL => 'ssn'
];
$select = $this->_db->select();
$select
    ->from('dummy_table', $columns)
```

But that won't work it will generate:

```
SELECT `dummy_table`.`id` AS `id`, `dummy_table`.`name` AS `name`, `dummy_table`.`age` AS `age`, `dummy_table`.`ssn` AS `` FROM `dummy_table`;
```

This query will fail. Is there any way you could do this using only Zend_Db ($this->_db->query('') is not an option)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')` ?

You could do :

```
$null = new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL');

$columns = [
    'id' => 'id',
    'name' => 'name',
    'age' => 'age',
    $null => 'ssn'
];
$select = $this->_db->select();
$select
    ->from('dummy_table', $columns);
```

Comment: It ignores that column: SELECT `dummy_table`.`id` AS `id`, `dummy_table`.`name` AS `name`, `dummy_table`.`age` AS `age` FROM `dummy_table`;

Comment: And using 'NULL' with quotes doesn't work ?

like 

$columns = [
    'id' => 'id',
    'name' => 'name',
    'age' => 'age',
    'NULL' => 'ssn'
];

Comment: SELECT `dummy_table`.`id` AS `id`, `dummy_table`.`name` AS `name`, `dummy_table`.`age` AS `age`, `dummy_table`.`ssn` AS `NULL` FROM `dummy_table`; This will work but the column will be named NULL instead of the actual alias that I need. I guess a solution would be replacing the key in the resulting php array, but I really wanted a method that selects it in the query